# What are the Standard Fields that are updated behind the scenes by Salesforce?

Tags: soql, formula, query, standard-objects, standard-field

Fields like **Opportunity - Total Revenue** (`Opportunity.Amount`) and **Opportunity Product - Total Price** (`OpportunityLineItem.TotalPrice`) are calculated by Salesforce automatically.

These calculations are not found in the metadata, but are instead handled by Salesforce internally.

How can I identify all of the fields that contain these types of "behind the scenes" calculations?

Comment: do you want to get these programmatically? Or to find in the doc?

Comment: @cropredy It would be nice to find these programmatically, but if there is an overview list of these fields in the documentation, that could be a start.

Comment: well, if you look at [Opportunity Object Ref doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm?q=opportunity) and read the notes for the fields; you can see which ones are calculated/derived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one place to find a comprehensive list of "magic" fields; you would have to check the documentation one page at a time for each object you're interested in. For example, if you look at [OpportunityLineItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm), you'll see entries like:

> CanUseQuantitySchedule
>
> Indicates whether the opportunity product can have a quantity schedule (true) or not (false). This field is read-only.

And:

> Discount
>
> Discount for the product as a percentage.
>
> When updating these records:
>
> - If you specify Discount without specifying TotalPrice, the TotalPrice is adjusted to accommodate the new Discount value, and the UnitPrice is held constant.
> - If you specify both Discount and Quantity, you must also specify either TotalPrice or UnitPrice so the system knows which one to automatically adjust.

There are dozens, if not hundreds, of these fields, and you'll only find that information in the documentation. In many cases, the field will be read-only (as the first example), but many will not, and have special rules. Also, look at the bottom of each object's field list for special rules for the object that may apply.